# Rearranging Cell array containing strings

Tags: string, matlab, replace, export-to-csv, cell-array

[image]

The contents in the cell array are as in the image showed above. I have two issues:

1. I have to move cells in columns to the preceding ones wherever there are `0s`. For example in `row 1`, the `1x7` cell has to come to the cell after `1x19` cell and so on.
2. While doing this, the cells with `[]` should also be moved replacing the preceding `0s`.

I tried using `strncmp`, `ismember` and other functions, but the `0` is throwing errors.

**UPDATE with working code**

The code is this:

It doesnt do all the work though. The cells being copied have to be deleted from the end.

```
for m=1:200
for i=1:46
    for j=1:199

        try
            if(tags{i,j}==0)
                for k=j:199
                    tags{i,k}=tags{i,k+1};
                    tags{i,k+1}='';
                end
            end
        catch exception

        end
    end
end
end
```

**EDIT - Question's part 2 : Not solved yet**

Each of the cells contains strings. Is there any way I can write them to a text file? 
All the strings in a cell have to be in the same line followed by a new line for the strings in the next cell.

Again, I tried this using a lot of functions, but I am unable to do it properly. I just get the first string in every cell to the text file.

Comment: But then you have a different number of elements in every row/column? How you want to deal with that? Fill with `[]`?

Comment: Yes. The ends can be filled with [].

Comment: You are able to write in your given exmaple the `1x7` cell into the first `0`? And the only problem is the deletion of the `0`? or do you have problems with the writing as well? Could you post your code which you have so far?

Comment: I suggest you create a t/f array with true wherever there isn't a zero, then you create a new array with all `[]`, and, for every row, fill cols 1:n with the non-zero entries.

Comment: @Jonas Actually I do have a t/f logical var with this info. Using this, I zeroed the non-existent cells from the matrix - I could not figure out how to fill the columns with non-zero cell of cell entries for every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach: Instead of iterating over the array, create a new one and fill in only the non-zero values (note: if you want to avoid making a new array, you can, in the loop, create a temporary copy of the row, empty the row in the array, and overwrite). With some clever array shuffling, you could do step 3 without the loop entirely, btw.

```
%# step 1: find non-zeros
nonZeros = cellfun(@(x) ~iscell(x) && ~isempty(x), tags);

%# step 2: create new array with all empty
[nRows,nCols] = size(tags);
newTags = cell(nRows,nCols);

%# step 3: for every row: copy the non-zero entries
[goodRows,goodCols] = find(nonZeros);

for iRow = 1:nCols;
    myGoodCols = goodCols(goodRows==iRow);
    nGoodCols = length(myGoodCols);
    if nGoodCols > 0 && nGoodCols < nCols
       %# shift everything
       newTags(iRow, 1:nGoodCols) = tags(iRow,myGoodCols);
    end
end

%# step 4 : write out tags
fid = fopen('tags.txt','w+');
for iRow = 1:nRows
    for iCol = 1:nCols
        if ~isempty(tags{iRow,iCol})
        fprintf(fid,'row %i col%i : ',iRow,iCol);
        fprintf(fid,'%s ',tags{iRow,iCol}{:});
        fprintf(fid,'\n');
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit 2** 
I guess the problem is that, your zeros weren't numbers but strings or chars as well. In that case just replace the `if`-arguments with a conversion from cell to matrix `cell2mat` as shown in the following code. Hopefully this solves your problem. 
 
*If not, could you post the code lines you used to create the zeros and other elements?*

```
for k=1:200 %For looping on all columns 
    for i=1:46 %For  max rows
    try     
        if cell2mat(test_mat(1,i))== '0'
            test_mat{1,i}='';
            for j=i:46 % For max columns
              try
                if cell2mat(test_mat(1,j))~='0' 
                    test_mat{1,i}=test_mat{1,j};
                    test_mat{1,j}='';
                    break
                end
                catch exception
              end
            end

        end
    catch exception
    end
    end
end
```

**Edit 1**

```
 for k=1:200 %For looping on all columns 
    for i=1:46 %For  max rows
    try
        if test_mat{k,i}==0
            test_mat{k,i}='';
            for j=i:46 % For max columns
              try
                if test_mat{k,j}~=0 
                    test_mat{k,i}=test_mat{k,j};
                    test_mat{k,j}='';
                    break
                end
                catch exception
              end
            end
        end
    catch exception
    end
    end
 end
```

Hey this should know replace your elements correctly.

**old Answer**
Hey not sure about 1 thing. But this should work

```
for k=1:max_row
   try
      if cell2mat(test_mat(1,k)) ==0 
         for j=k:max_row
           if cell2mat(test_mat(1,j)) ~= 0
               test_mat(1,k) = test_mat(1,j);
               test_mat(1,j) = {''};
               break
           end
         end
      end
      catch exception
   end
end
```

Here i am looping only through the first row (for all rows you could add another loop including this code). The first if checks if the element is 0. If so the second if checks for a non zero element in the same row but later column. Then i write that element into the `0` place and replace it with`[]`. 
I ain't sure if its an effective solution regarding runtime.

 And the thing i ain't sure is your 7th line. What should happen there? Does the 3 non zero element `<1x7>cell` go to the `<1x11>cell` place, stays where it is or does it go back one slot?

Comment: In the 7th line, the 0 can be made blank. But your code throws this error: Error using cell2mat (line 53)
Cannot support cell arrays containing cell
arrays or objects.
Error in movingzeros (line 18)
   if cell2mat(test_mat(1,k)) ==0

Comment: Ah my code works only for matrices which are filled with numbers and then converted to cells so that you can store different sized data in one structure. What kind of data is inside your cells?

Comment: Strings. Thats the reason, I put this question up. Else it was easy.

Comment: @SharathChandra Hey i think i fixed my answer. Would be nice if you could test it. One point i didn't try is what happens if the last element of a column is `0`and what happens if there is no code to replace the `0` with

Comment: @SharathChandra I changed the code again. Now it replaces all `0`with `[]` if there is no further nonzero element in the column

Comment: It doenst work - some 0s are being replaced by [], but there's no movement seen!

Comment: @SharathChandra I made another edit. Maybe the problem was that my zeros where still numbers. You can try the new code. If it doesn't work, pls post the code you use to create your elements.

Comment: The problem is solved actually, I posted the code in the update. Could you please help me solve the second issue?